# "Skills that are useful" or "skills those are useful"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns

I am used to using the phrase *that is* a lot, for example: "I have a skill that is useful in this situation". What if I use a plural form? What is the correct sentence of the following two?

> - I have some skills that are useful in this situation.
> - I have some skills those are useful in this situation.

Comment: Drop the word "skills" and see which sounds right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, in your examples, it is correct to use *that*, and not *those*.

Why?  The *that* in your sentence is being used as a pronoun to introduce a relative restrictive clause, not as a pronoun referring to *skills*, so it doesn't get pluralized.  Here's a helpful definition:

> **[that](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/that)** (pronoun) \thət, ˈthat\ —18. used to introduce a restrictive relative clause  ⇒ (e.g. the book *that* we want)

Essentially, your sentence

> *I have some skills that are useful in this situation*.

is saying:

> *My skills are useful in this situation.*

However, if you add the right punctuation, then the word *that* could be used as a pronoun referring to the subject of the sentence:

> *I have a skill (debating); that (skill) is useful in this situation*.

And, in this case, the plural form *would* be used when referring to more than one skill:

> *I have skills (debating, logic, and public speaking); these (skills) are useful in this situation*.

Furthermore, if you are talking about someone else's skills, you could change the *these* to *those*:

> *She has skills (debating, logic, and public speaking); those are useful in this situation*.

Hopefully, I've provided some examples that are useful for your situation.

(or, *I've provided some examples; hopefully, these are useful for your situation.*)

Comment: Actually "that" is not a conjunction there. Just do the test, if it can be replaced with "which" or "who" it's obviously not a conjunction. In fact the *that* in "skills that are useful" is so strikingly different from the *that* in "he said that he was", I am amazed you haven't noticed. What's worse, the *that* in "that is useful" is not the same as the *that* in "that skill is useful", either. The former is a pronoun, the latter a determiner.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道: I appreciate the feedback; I could be mistaken.  Dictionaries I consulted indicate that when the word _that_ is used to introduce a subordinate clause, its part of speech is classified as a conjunction. It seemed this was the case in "I have skills that are useful" – I thought "are useful" was a subordinate clause, but I'm no expert at sentence parsing. At least I got the pronoun part right, though. When I typed "that (skill) is useful in this situation," the parens were meant to imply the sentence read "that is useful in this situation" and the word "that" referred to "skill."

Comment: -1.  This answer is very misleading.  Here, "that" is absolutely _not_ being used as a conjunction.  It's a relative pronoun.  But it's true that "that" is correct in this context, not "those".

Comment: @DavidWallace: Thanks for the reminder that I needed to go back and fix this answer.  Thanks also to RegDwight for pointing out my error initially.  I think I've got it correct now.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, J.R.  I have removed my downvote and replaced it with an upvote.

Answer (score 5):

The only alternative to *that* in such sentences is *which*. *That*  (in this context) is a relative pronoun (or a clause subordinator for some linguists), while *those* is a demonstrative pronoun and a demonstrative determiner.

Comment: You left out 'here'; *that* can also be a demnstrative pronoun, which is presumably why the question was asked.

Comment: @TimLymington: Yes, it's not always easy to get everything into one quick answer. Not sure what you mean about 'here' though.